# How to use markdown in card description?

Tags: trello, markdown

I cannot figure out how to use [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) to have formated text in the Trello card description.
Please give some clue as to how to achieve this.

Comment: Give an example of what you're trying to do so we have an idea of what you're trying to do

Answer (score 12):

You use Markdown simply by inserting Markdown "code" directly into the card description as you type. When you save the description your Markdown code will automatically be converted to formatted text.

If your issue is that you don't understand how to write in Markdown, there is a detailed explanation of how it all works on [the Markdown syntax page](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax). If you're just looking for a quick list of the commands, I would recommend using the [Markdown tester (and cheatsheet)](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/dingus), which gives you a list of the basic commands and an easy converter so you can make sure what you're typing will convert properly.

An example first, and then how it works:

Copy the following block of text into a card description to [see what it does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqsWB.png):

```
This card is for discussing the integration of ![](http://i.imgur.com/sZ4HY.jpg) modules:

1. __Foo__
2. _Bar_
3. [Markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)

Any other discussions are considered **off topic** and you will be *shunned*.
```

#### How it works:

It works similar to HTML code, in that you insert the Markdown syntax directly in the text as you write it. For example, a single underline _ or star * surrounding any chunk of text will *italicize, or emphasize*.

So `_italicize this text_` and `*italicize this text*` are the same as `<em>italicize this text</em>` in HTML.

A double underline __ or double star ** surrounding any chunk of text will **bold, or make strong**. The same as `<strong>bold this text</strong>` in HTML.

There are quick codes for many things:

- `#` preceding a line to make it a heading (`<h1> </h1>` in HTML)
- `========` or `--------` under words to make them into a `<h1>` or `<h2>`
- ordered or unordered lists
- blockquotes
- inserting images
- and many more

Check out the links to the syntax page and the cheatsheet for the full list of commands and more examples.